# How to extract payload from packet in queue of iptables

Tags: tcp, network-programming, http-headers, iptables, netfilter

I am using libnetfilter_queue library. But i couldn't figure out a way to extract payload in the call back function. I am bit new. A detailed help will be highly appreciated! Actually i further wish to extract http header from the payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have gotten till callback,  get the file descriptor associated with the nfqueue handler using the following api.

```
int nfq_fd (struct nfq_handle *h);
```

Then call a standard recv() which takes a descriptor to read from, a buffer in which it fills the data and the length of buffer.

```
if(recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) >= 0)
        printf("pkt received in buf\n");
```

Now buf contains the entire packet. I don't think there is an explicit api available to parse http. You can read the spec of http standard and skip bytes up to the fields you are looking for.

[libnetfilerqueue](http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#ga32703f66bfe86e5d0d6a348511628d45)